# Extracting specific text from a Word file

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a Word document that has font sizes of 14 and 18, and the document is of 1500 pages.

I have to make specific changes to the font 14 and font 18, and so after searching, I came across VBA for Word that would allow me to do this easily.

Since I have never done VBA before, I tried this:

```
Sub tryIt()

If Selection.Font.Size = 18 Then
MsgBox ("test")

End If
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work... The msgbox() was just to see if it recognized the text properly.

So how can I separate / differentiate between font size 14 and 18 in a Word document and implement this in a vb script?

Is there any way to extract the 14 and 18 sized text or search for it so that I can do a find/replace?

Comment: I have not got Word to hand at the moment, but you can record a macro using Find->Special to get rough code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what wasn't working with your code. However, for starters try this:

```
Sub tryIt()
    Dim findRange As Range
    Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    findRange.Find.ClearFormatting
    findRange.Find.Font.Size = 18

    Do While findRange.Find.Execute(findtext:="") = True
        findRange.Select
        'Do something here

        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to tell what you're after exactly, but the following macro will replace all contiguous text that is in font size 14 with the text "fuzz".

```
Sub TryIt()
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Size = 14
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = "fuzz"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

If this isn't what you're after, you may need to clarify a bit what you mean.