# How to read font size of each word in a word document using POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, word-processor

I am trying to find out whether there exist anything in the word document that has a font of 2. However, I have not been able to do this. To begin with, I've tried to read the font of each word in a sample word document that only has one line and 7 words. I am not getting the correct results.

Here is my code:

```
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument (fileStream);
WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
Range range = doc.getRange()
String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
  Paragraph pr = range.getParagraph(i);
  int k = 0
  while (true) {
     CharacterRun run = pr.getCharacterRun(k++);
     System.out.println("Color: " + run.getColor());
     System.out.println("Font: " + run.getFontName());
     System.out.println("Font Size: " + run.getFontSize());
     if (run.getEndOffSet() == pr.getEndOffSet())
       break;
  }
}
```

However, the above code always doubles the font size. i.e. if the actual font size in the document is 12 then it outputs 24 and if actual font is 8 then it outputs 16.

Is this the correct way to read font size from a word document ??

Comment: you could possibly try to use [this Word-VBA logic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5160803/2143262) (if possible in java)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct way; the measurement is in half points.

In a docx, you'd have something like:

```
<w:rPr>

  <w:sz w:val="28" /> 

</w:rPr>
```

[ECMA 376 spec on @sz](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/sz_1.html) defines the unit as [ST_HpsMeasure (Measurement in Half-Points)](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/ST_HpsMeasure.html)

Its the same with the binary doc format, which HWPF supports. If you look at [[MS-DOC]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313153%28v=office.12%29.aspx), you'll see it also specifies the size of text in half-points.