# Java Word doc docx font

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to read the font size of the words in docx file in java. I have used Apache POI library but it convert all the file i try to read into txt file.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584413/how-to-read-font-size-of-each-word-in-a-word-document-using-poi

Comment: Thank you for the help but it only accepts the doc format i want both doc and docx format.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, for `.docx` documents, you'll need XWPF-library, and for `.doc` HWPF - you can't use one library for both of them.

Here's a code, which reads a `.docx` FontSize:

```
public void readFontSizeFromDocx() throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("templates/ExampleFontSize.docx");
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(is);

    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : doc.getParagraphs())
    {
        for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns())
        {
            System.out.println(run.getFontSize());
        }
    }
}
```

Also, take a look at the [Apache Documentation](http://poi.apache.org/document/) - there are also many useful examples which explain, how to use it.